# SwiftUI Environment Object alternative in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, swiftui

I learned SwiftUI before starting to learn flutter and I could not understand how to have something that is similar to Environment object in SwiftUI?

One solution I could think of is using singletons, But I am not sure if using singletons are a good flutter architecture solution.

For example in SwiftUI you would access data like so:

```
struct MyView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject DataController data

    var body: some View {
        Text(data.title)
    } 
}
```

And the `DataController` would look like this:

```
class DataController {
    title = "Hello!"
}
```

On the other hand in flutter if I will use singleton it will look like this:

```
class MyWidget extends StateLessWidget {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Text(DataController.data.title);
    } 
}
```

And the `DataController` in flutter is using a `singleton`:

```
class DataController {
    static DataController data = DataController();
    title = "Hello!";
}
```

Is there a better way achieving this feature without passing arguments and values down the widget tree with provider package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best option I found is GetX package: https://pub.dev/packages/get

It is very convenient and handy, very similar to `EnvironmentObject`

Answer (score 2):

I'm actually trying to figure out the same problem, but I think that the provider Package might be the right choice.
There are plenty of good tutorials and a complete installation guide on pub.dev